# Cannot enable or disable Mail plug-ins

Tags: mail.app, mojave, plugins, gpg

I have two Mail.app plug-ins installed: "GPGMailLoader.mailbundle" and "Smallcubed MailSuite.mailbundle".  Currenly, GPG is enabled, and works, and MailSuite is disabled.

However, when I toggle either plugin (i.e. MailSuite to on or GPG to off), and restart Mail, the change hasn't taken.  So I cannot use MailSuite, nor disable GPG.

I have tried:

- Reinstalling MacOS Mojave in-place (did not fix).
- Creating a new user (everything works for new user).

How can I further investigate this?

Comment: As a new user fixed this, have you tried to reset your Mail preferences and checked it again ?

Comment: @Udhy as in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail-shared.plist`? Deleting that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I moved my `~/Library/Mail` folder to the Desktop, reset mail "[to factory settings](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5118986?answerId=5118986021#5118986021)", then re-imported all messages from the moved folder.  It took about a day, including the backup I did first.

Following the above "reset" instructions involves deleting `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/`.  When I was perusing the new `~/Library/*` and `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/*` setup, after relaunching Mail, there were differences before and after, in particular which items lived in the container and which lived in the real `~/Library`.  This may be a clue to a cause, but at least there is now a sledgehammer solution.